Is it possible to use pins 32-53 as GPIO on a Raspberry Pi4
My scenario is that I have a raspberry pi 4 using GPIO 2-27, and I am able to freely set the pins as inputs or outputs
print("Setting pins 2-8 as INPUTS with PUD_UP")
for pin in range(2, 9):
    try:
        self.pi.set_mode(pin, pigpio.INPUT)
        self.pi.set_pull_up_down(pin, pigpio.PUD_UP)
        self.pi.write(pin, pigpio.LOW)
        print(f"pin #{pin} set!")
    except pigpio.error as e:
        print(f"Error setting pin #{pin}: {e}")

print("Setting pins 9-27 as INPUTS with PUD_DOWN")
for pin in range(9, 28):
    try:
        self.pi.set_mode(pin, pigpio.INPUT)
        self.pi.set_pull_up_down(pin, pigpio.PUD_DOWN)
        self.pi.write(pin, pigpio.LOW)
        print(f"pin #{pin} set!")
    except pigpio.error as e:
        print(f"Error setting pin #{pin}: {e}")

I know it's also possible to use pins 28-53 in the context of being able to read pins
def read_gpio_banks(self):
    bank1 = self.pi.read_bank_1()
    bank2 = self.pi.read_bank_2()

    print("GPIO Bank 1 (0-31):")
    for pin in range(0, 32):
        level = (bank1 >> pin) & 1
        print(f"GPIO {pin}: Level={level}")

    print("\nGPIO Bank 2 (32-53):")
    for pin in range(32, 54):
        level = (bank2 >> (pin - 32)) & 1
        print(f"GPIO {pin}: Level={level}")

But if I try to set the mode or write to pins 32-53
print("Setting pins 28-53 as INPUTS with no pull-up or pull-down")
for pin in range(28, 54):
    try:
        self.pi.set_mode(pin, pigpio.INPUT)
        self.pi.set_pull_up_down(pin, pigpio.PUD_OFF)
        self.pi.write(pin, pigpio.LOW)
        print(f"pin #{pin} set!")
    except pigpio.error as e:
        print(f"Error setting pin #{pin}: {e}")

I get permissions errors
Error setting pin #28: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #29: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #30: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #31: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #32: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #33: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #34: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #35: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #36: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #37: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #38: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #39: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #40: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #41: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #42: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #43: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #44: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #45: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #46: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #47: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #48: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #49: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #50: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #51: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #52: 'no permission to update GPIO'
Error setting pin #53: 'no permission to update GPIO'

What can I do to use those second bank pins? I was explicitly told it's possible but I have no idea what's missing

This question may yield more help over at Raspberry PI stackexchange where folks can speak to both the programming and the physical set up to help troubleshoot further.

Just a potentially silly question: Do you run the code with sudo permissions?

@MSH yeah I tried with sudo and without but it's the same problem. It's a similar issue to if you were to try to write to pins 0  & 1 where you can read the status on those pins but can't write to them

You know what. Since you try-catch the code you can't knıow if the code raises the error on set_mode, set_pull_up_down or write. use a debugger, add print between each line or remove the try-catch block to make sure.

You need to configure pin control properly.
